# Is there a name for “fear of olives” in English?

Tags: single-word-requests, etymology, greek, phobias

I know people with an actual fear of olives. Is there a name in English for this phobia?

I have not been able to find anything in the usual websites.

Comment: You mean "allergic" to olives?

Comment: @Josh61 No, I mean really phobic to olives: not being able to be in a room where there are olives.

Comment: @tchrist Maybe yo would like to write it as an answer to my question, and not just as a comment, together with some references for *'eliaphobia'*.

Comment: There is no name for fear of olives,(as far as I know)  but ***lachanophobia*** is the fear
of vegetables. http://common-phobias.com/Lachano/phobia.htm

Comment: It's mentioned here: http://biblehub.com/greek/1636.htm

Comment: Is there a reason that olives in particular are singled out? (Like what about figs) Is ther a possible rational fear of them like maybe allergies?

Comment: @Mitch The reason for my question is that I do know some people with fear of olives, in the sense that they get nervious and worried if there are olives in the table. It is a phobia, not and allergy, as nearly all of those people have never tasted olives. Why not cucumbers, or pineapples...? I do not know, I am just talking about what I have seen and heard.

Comment: Wasn't Popeye's girl friend called Olive Oil? Could it have something to do with a reaction to her, do you think?

Comment: Vincent, is that actually fear or simply dislike or disgust? Though not impossible, at first glance it seems very implausible to have a neurotic fear of olives.

Comment: @Mitch Again, believe me, it is a phobia, or at least it is closer to a phobia than to a disgust feeling. Maybe it is more common in my region or country than in yours, but I know one girl with that fear, and I've read and heard about other people with the same fear. It is like an irrational fear to see (and smell, taste, etc.) olives.

Comment: People, thank you for that -1!!! Now I see I am understood, and my fear to be missunderstood was unreal... #sarcasm

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## *Elaeophobia* or *eleophobia*

Phobias are productive in English, by which I mean that in English when one wants to describe a speciﬁc phobia, one simply identiﬁes the Ancient Greek word   corresponding to the thing feared, adjusting as needed to serve as a preﬁx, and then sufﬁxes *‑phobia* to it.  This is an open set because people’s fears are unbounded.  So all you need to do is ﬁgure out what the Greek word for olive is, and there you go.

The answer is that Ancient Greek uses [*ἐλαία*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%B5%CE%BB%CE%B9%CE%AC#Greek) to mean olive — and [*ἔλαιον*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BC%94%CE%BB%CE%B1%CE%B9%CE%BF%CE%BD#Ancient_Greek) for olive oil.  This gives a preﬁx combining form we can use to derive a recognizable technical name for this exotic fear.

According to the OED, there indeed exists a preﬁx variously transliterated *elæo‑*, *elaeo‑*, or *eleo‑* which is derived from Greek *ἕλαιο‑ν* meaning olive oil, and can be used in technical words. Both English and Italian use it in this way, although English is more apt to use the Latin cognate *oleo‑*. Italian sometimes spells it *elaio‑*, but English does not appear to do that.

For Greeks and indeed other Mediterranean peoples, olive oil is the default oil they use for everything, and therefore the speciﬁc word gets used in a generic way. So just as a water-resistant substance is *hydrophobic*, an oil-resistant one is *eleophobic* (apparently the preferred spelling).

Normally then *eleo‑* is a preﬁx meaning oil in general, but drawing on its origin in Greek there is no reason that one cannot also use this word for the specific thing if that’s the sense one wants.  Of the three possible spelling variants, the last one is now the most common:

1. *elæophobia, elæophobic*
2. *elaeophobia, elaeophobic*
3. *eleophobia, eleophobic*

However, you might elect the second spelling to help folks think back to the more restricted sense instead of the general one.

Comment: Good answer, I'd add that this term is as rare (if it was ever used before) as probably those unfortunate people who are affected by this unusual phobia.

Answer (score 3):

The English words for the various "phobias" are simply constructed from Greek roots. This is done as-needed by the psychiatric community.

So the answer to any question of the form "Is there an English word for fear of *X*", where *X* has a word for it in Greek is "**Yes**". The word for it is "*Y*phobia", where *Y* is the Greek word for *X*.

In other words, asking any such question just devolves into asking "What is the Greek word for *X*?'

Comment: so ... fearoolive fearoanything! easy!